# Power BI Service: Date getting changed during Scheduled Refresh

Tags: powerbi

Here is what is correctly working:

1. We are using Power BI Desktop and pull data from Google Sheets using CData ODBC Connector.
2. When we refresh the data on Power BI desktop, the date shows as 1/7/2020.(1st July 2020), dd/mm/yyyy .  This date is correct. This date format is also correct.
3. My Computer is set to Regional Settings: Regional Settings: English(India)
4. Power BI's Regional Settings is also set to English(India)
5. The Google Sheets is also set to English(India)
6. And when we publish the above data to Power BI Service , the date in Power BI Service is also    1/7/2020 , ie, The date is correct, but the date format is mm/dd/yyyy. We don't mind this at all. We don't care about the date format at all.

Here is what is going wrong:

1. When we schedule automatic refresh, the date changes to 6/12/2020 and gets fixed at 6/12/2020. This date is Wrong (again, we don't care about the date format). It's the date which is wrong!

We have contacted Cdata and Power BI but neither of them have solved this query.

This has been going on for months now. How can we resolve this?